# Need help running a thread in background with button press (android app)

Tags: android

I am trying to write code for my android app where when i press a button it will run a function in the background and exit whenever I press the button again. Can someone please explain to me how i can do that. I know it is around threads, but I just cant figure it out. below is the code.

```
    public void onMonitorClick(final View view){ //the button
    if (isBLEEnabled()) {
        if (!isDeviceConnected()) {
                // do nothing
        } else if (monitorvis == 0) {
            showMonitor(); //sets button to display "Stop" and sets monitorvis to 1;
            monitorStop = 1;

        } else if (monitorvis == 1) {
            hideMonitor(); //sets button to display "monitor" and sets monitorvis to 0;
            monitorStop = 0;
            run(); //this is the thread i want to run in the background, how do i 
                    //make it exit whenever i press onMonitorClick again?
        }
    } 
    else {
        showBLEDialog();
    }
}

protected void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssi();
            rssilevel = ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssiValue();
            mRSSI.setText(String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");
            detectRange(rssilevel);
        }
    });
}
```

ALSO, how can I make thread run() with a delay because right now it is polling those functions too quickly. PLEASE explain by showing a code snippet or modifying my code. Thank you soo much

trying this code for now, no success

```
public void doWork() {  
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
ScheduledFuture future = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssi();
        rssilevel = ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssiValue();
        mRSSI.setText(String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");
        detectRange(rssilevel);
    }
}, 
0, // How long to delay the start
500, // How long between executions
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // The time unit used
```

}

next edit for help

```
    public void doWork() {
    if(mScheduleExecutorService == null) {
        mScheduleExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }
    if (mScheduleFuture == null) {
        mScheduleFuture = mScheduleExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    do {
                    ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssi();
                    rssilevel = ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssiValue();
                    mRSSI.setText(String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");
                    detectRange(rssilevel); } while (monitorStop != 3);
                }
        }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ScheduledExecutor in this case. There are many examples around, but here is a quick snipped:

```
ScheduleExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ScheduleFuture future = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
             // Perform your recurring method calls in here.
        }
    }
}, 
0, // How long to delay the start
500, // How long between executions
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // The time unit used
```

Be sure to shutdown the ExecutorService when you're done. So whenever your app is about to exit (or perhaps when they press the button a second time):

```
service.shutdownNow(); // or service.shutdown();
```

For the above snippet you'll need the following imports:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

---

Looks like you're close and on your way. I would keep a reference to the future and the service so I could terminate, shutdown, etc. in other areas. Try something along the lines of:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService mScheduleExecutorService;
private ScheduledFuture mScheduleFuture;

public void onMonitorClick(final View view){ //the button
    if (isBLEEnabled()) {
        if (!isDeviceConnected()) {
                // do nothing
        } else if (monitorvis == 0) {
            showMonitor(); //sets button to display "Stop" and sets monitorvis to 1;
            monitorStop = 1;
            shutdownExecutor();
        } else if (monitorvis == 1) {
            hideMonitor(); //sets button to display "monitor" and sets monitorvis to 0;
            monitorStop = 0;
            doWork(); //this is the thread i want to run in the background, how do i 
                    //make it exit whenever i press onMonitorClick again?
        }
    } 
    else {
        showBLEDialog();
    }
}

public void doWork() {
    if(mScheduleExecutorService == null) {
        mScheduleExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }
    if (mScheduleFuture == null) {
        mScheduleFuture = mScheduleExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssi();
                rssilevel = ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssiValue();
                mRSSI.setText(String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");
                detectRange(rssilevel);
            }
        }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}

private void shutdownExecutor() {
    if (mScheduleExecutorService != null && !mScheduleExecutorService.isShutdown()) {
        mScheduleExecutorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am playing aroun with this, and i am having issues figuring out what to import to get it to work

Comment: please look at what i did so far (i added some code in question). doesnt seem like the code ever executes, any advice please

Comment: yeah i got those figured out, now the issue is nothing happens when i call doWork

Comment: thanks for your help we are getting closer to the solution! Right now it does run the doWork, but I want to loop the code inside of it. I did this by a do a while, but it still only runs one time, any idea on this? look at code i posted please.

Comment: Hrm. Couple things, looks like I may have had an extra bracket in my code snippet. Be sure to check yours and see if you're getting a syntax error.

Also, the idea behind the scheduled executor is that it creates a thread that will perform your methods on a recurring time frame. For the example above, it will have a 0 millisecond delay, so it will start immediately, then it will wait 500 milliseconds between executions before it runs again. It will continue to loop until you tell the future to cancel() or the service to shutdown/terminate.

Comment: yeah there was some braket issues, but i resolved that. currently i got the code working to the point that it only runs doWork() one time. In the Logcat it only shows the functions running once. cant seem to make it run multiple times for some reason.

Comment: Hrm, I'm not sure what would be the issue at that point. If you're attempting to toggle the Service and Future by turning it off and on again via the button click, then you'll need to make sure you set the Service and Future to null in the shutdown() method. But if that's the route we are going down, you'll most likely want to look into Handlers or good 'ol Java threads.

Comment: damn, ill look into it more, i had a uithread going before, it would work the way i wanted, but it would not allow me to do anything else while its running the thread.